# Magento 1.8 can't login, no error displayed

Tags: admin, login

I got problem for admin login for weeks, I tried all solution I found, none of them works. Could anybody help me out from the issue please?

The solution I tried :

1. add formkey
2. commment cookie setting in Varien.php
3. clear cookie

The solution works, but only works for the first login is:

delete content under /var/cache and /var/session

After that, I can login once. Once logout, can't login again.

Thanks a lot if anyone can help.

Comment: This might be helpful, http://blog.philwinkle.com/i-cant-login-to-magento-admin/

Comment: Finally know why this happening, server reached space quote, and can't generate new session, stupid mistake...